# Netty client side connection close too slow

Tags: java, netty, nio

Here is my client side source code:

```
public class Client 
{
    Server server;
    Logger logger;
    ChannelHandlerContext responseCtx;
    public Client(String host, int port, int mode, String fileName)
    {
        server=null;
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try 
        {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap(); 
            b.group(group);
            b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
            b.remoteAddress(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
            b.handler(new MyChannelInitializer(server, mode,fileName));
            ChannelFuture f = b.connect().sync();
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
            System.out.println("client started");
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally 
        {
            try {
                group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Calendar endTime=Calendar.getInstance();
            System.out.println("client stopped "+endTime.getTimeInMillis());
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Client c=new Client("localhost",1234,MyFtpServer.SENDFILE,"D:\\SITO3\\Documents\\Xmas-20141224-310.jpg");
    }
}
```

Here is my File Transfer Complete Listener source code:

```
public class FileTransferCompleteListener implements ChannelFutureListener 
{
    Server server;

    public FileTransferCompleteListener(Server server) 
    {
        this.server=server;
    }

    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture cf) throws Exception 
    {
        Calendar endTime=Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("File transfer completed! "+endTime.getTimeInMillis());
        if(server!=null)
            server.stop();
        else
            cf.channel().close();
    }
}
```

Here is the execution result:

```
File transfer completed! 1451446521041
client started
client stopped 1451446523244
```

I want to know why it takes about 2 second to close connection.
Is it any way to reduce it?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [shutdownGracefully(long quietPeriod, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.html#shutdownGracefully%28long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29), you can specify the quietPeriod, by default it is a couple of seconds.
I’m not sure what the implications are if you shorten this.

Comment: In fact, I am developing FTP server. In active mode, when the user list the directory content, the listing display in client side quickly, however, it need a while to return the control to user.